# Visualizing Cauchy Sequences

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, real-numbers

Is it possible to "visualize" Cauchy sequences? I'm struggling to understand the intuition behind the definition, as given:

A sequence {$p_{n}$} is Cauchy if for all positive real numbers $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{Z}$ $s.t.$ $\forall m,n \geq N$, $d(p_{m}, p_{n}) < \epsilon$.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: just in case, there are some plottings in the Wikipedia page (right-top side) that seem to be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terms of Cauchy sequence eventually are squeezed ...

But note that
When it comes to visualizing a math concept, one only can think about finite dimension like $\Bbb R^2$ or $\Bbb R^3$ (with Euclidean norm)!

And we know Cauchy sequences in finite dimension (with usual metric) are exactly convergent sequences, and visualizing a convergent sequence is not a big deal !